# Adherence values of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence. If $x_{2n-1}=-\frac{1}{n}$ and $x_{2n}=1+\frac{1}{n}$ and $X_n = \{ x_n, x_{n+1},\ldots\}$, verify that $\inf X_{2n-1} = -\frac{1}{n}$ and $\sup X_{2n-1} - \sup X_{2n} = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$ and prove that $\liminf x_n = 0$ and  $\limsup x_n = 1$. Besides, prove that those are the only adherence values of the sequence $\{x_n\}$.

I was able to prove that  $\liminf x_n = 0$ and  $\limsup x_n = 1$, but I don't know how to start on verifying the first part and proving that they are the only adherence values of the sequence.

Comment: They way you wrote it, $X_n$ seems to be a set with two elements.  Comparing the to to find the inf should be straightforward.  Maybe I misunderstand.

Comment: I just did an edit on that.

Comment: If 0 < w < 1. You can find n such that 1/n < w< 1 - 1/n so for m > 2n, |x_m - w|> min (w-1/n,1 - 1/n - w) so w isn't an adherent point.

Comment: Oops I got the signs wrong.  But the idea, is the same.  x < 0 then x < -1/n for some n, so for m > 2n, x_m -x > -1/n - x.  Similar for x > 1.  And for 0 <x <1 then |x - x_n| < min (x,1-x).

Comment: As for inf.  -1/n < -1/(n+k) and -1/n < 0 < 1 < 1 + 1/(n+j) so inf = -1/n.